# Writing chess moves on paper

Tags: analysis

Is the FIDE rule for writing chess moves with pen and paper by both players discarded or not mandatory in World chess championship games?

In case yes, why it is discarded or not mandatory to write chess moves?

If i am not wrong, the players were writing the moves on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Most major tournaments (including the World Championship) are commonly played on DGT Boards which automatically record the notation for the players. This has some distinct advantages;

- Legibility
- Improved ability for broadcasting
- Reduces need to transcribe games after the fact into a digital format.

That being said I believe it is still a requirement for players to manually record there games. I don't believe these records are discarded as they are submitted to the tournament organisers who technically own them.

In regards to why pen and paper. It minimises opportunities and accusations of cheating. If I was playing over the board to you and was entering in each move onto a computer (through something like chess base) who is to say I didn't enable an engine to quickly analyse a move?

Comment: Thanks. https://www.google.com/search?q=Chess+moves+paper&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjS4_-zqsfrAhXoh0sFHbViCYgQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=Chess+moves+paper&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQDDIECCMQJzIFCAAQzQI6CAgAEAgQBxAeOgcIIxCwAhAnOgQIABANOggIABANEAUQHjoECB4QClDgK1juQGDJRWgAcAB4AIABoASIAcYJkgEHMC41LjUtMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img&ei=cOpNX9LrEeiPrtoPtcWlwAg#imgrc=6_lRwfNYliDeQM Is the Chess moves paper standardized in terms of Paper type,format, dimensions etc according to FIDE rules? I mean the Chess players have to use the same Chess paper universally in any tournament?

Comment: I doubt they are that pedantic. from my experience they have usually been A4 in size , standard lay out numbered down the page sort of set up usually 2 or 3 columns, section down the bottom for outcome , section at the top for players etc. 

I think you'll find they differ between tournaments.

Side Note: noticed you have been asking a large number of questions about tournaments and tournament rules... have you refered to the find handbooks? 
https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018 would be a good start

Comment: Thanks. Later on, Is it mandatory for the players to scan or take a photo copy of the Chess moves papers to feed it for recording the match into a electronic system?

Comment: No that would be the responsibility of the arbitrators and officials.